# How to avoid overlapping of text in iPad?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode8, nslayoutconstraint, ios-autolayout

The UI of my app looks fine on iPhone but the text gets overlapped in iPad.  Can anyone tell me how to resolve this problem?I have used constraints as given in the screenshot.

[image]

the text of button(i.e "unable to sign in?") looks like this

[image]

[image]

Thank you!

Comment: Show your storyboard of this VC.

Comment: If you want your UI keeps likely on iPhone and iPad, please make constraints only in Any, Any.

Comment: @Lumialxk she is using x-code 8. So she does not need to use size classes like this because it is auto-manageable by the x-code.

Comment: @sarita Post the constraints of both buttons.

Comment: @sarita please give me your mail id then i will send you video for how can set constraints to your view.